# Custom Sitecore 9 form field is not getting replaced by value when used as a token in the mail using exm

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms

When my page loads with a form, the query string contains a GUID of a property detail item. I want the URL of this property in the mail that triggers on submit button click of the form.

I created a **model**

```
 public class PropertyInfoViewModel : FieldViewModel
{
    public string PropertyUrl { get; set; }

    protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
    {
        base.InitItemProperties(item);
        try
        {
            if (Guid.TryParse(WebUtil.GetSafeQueryString("itemId"), out Guid propertyId))
            {
                var product = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(WebUtil.GetSafeQueryString("itemId"));  // get product with the id
                var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
                options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
                PropertyUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(product, options);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error occured while processing customised form fields.", ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

and a **view**

```
<div class="component col-md-12 link common-link common-breadcrumb">
<div class="component-content">
    <div class="field-link">
        @{
            <a href="@Model.PropertyUrl" class="">Property</a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I added a field type at the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Basic` [image]

And dragged and dropped it onto my form.[image]

Finally, On the submit click added a send mail submit action. The `email campaign` selected reads this value as a token `$form_PropertyLink$`. But this value is not getting replaced in the mail, it is coming as it is. The form values like firstname, surname are getting replaced. Am I missing something? Any help would be highly appreciated